# MIFARE classic card APDU authentication failure

Tags: zebra-printers, apdu, mifare, contactless-smartcard

I have been trying to authenticate MIFARE classic 4k contactless cards using Identive SDI010 Contactless Reader within Zebra ZXP SERIES 7 PRO printer. I can successfully load keys using below command

```
FF 82 00 60 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF
response - 9000
```

However authentication command always fails

```
FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 06 60 00
response - 6982 Security status not satisfied (not authenticated)
```

I also tried APDU commands from other similar posts but all are giving same response. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure that your card has the transport key (`FF FF FF FF FF FF`) set as key A for sector 1 (block 6)? Also, the use manual of that reader indicates that the last byte of the APDU command should be set to 0x01, so I would try to use `FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 06 60 01`.

Comment: @MichaelRoland I tried last byte as 01 but seeing same error. Is there any alternative way to verify transport key other than try to authenticate?

Comment: Not really. You would pobably want to try with a card for which you verified by other means (different reader) that keyA is set to `FF FF FF FF FF FF` for that sector.

Comment: So based on your answer, the authentication key that you tried was simply wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This commands worked for me.

```
FF 82 00 60 06 A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 03 60 01
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the ZXP3. Using the Mifare 1K test app in the PCSC-Sharp library, this worked:

Load Authentication Keys: FF-82-00-60-06-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF

SW1 SW2 = 90 00

General Authenticate: FF-86-00-00-05-01-00-08-60-00

SW1 SW2 = 90 00